# How can I get all the ACM Computing Classification System tags as strings?

Tags: html, web-scraping, web-crawler

So I'm writing an app where there's a  HTML tag which should have all the ACM CCS tags/fields as options and basically users should be able to select one or more of these tags and assign them.

However how can I go about getting all the ACM CCS tags as strings in the first place, so I can create the  element with the proper options in the first place?

Getting them manually isn't really an option as there are probably thousands of them by the looks of it.

Considering they're part of the academic culture I thought they'd already been extracted at some point by someone in a certain format and then shared somewhere but I couldn't find any such thing.

For reference, if you don't know what I'm talking about, I want all the names of all the CCS tags in no particular order from this site: https://dl.acm.org/ccs

So for example, in the end I wanna obtain such strings as "General and reference", "Hardware" , etc.
I've looked into web crawlers and the likes but I seriously have no clue how to even use one, let alone build one. As far as I've seen all these names are stored inside `<li>` tags so if I had something that'd "parse" the whole site with all its pages and then store the content of all the `<li>` tags it encounters as strings that would work.

Comment: On that same page, if you click in the upper-right corner  of the view you can switch from the "Interactive View" to the "Flat View," which appears to contain the complete list?  Is that what you need?

Comment: *something that'd "parse" the whole site with all its pages* Yep, that's pretty much the definition of web-scraping. I get the feeling you want a tutorial on how to build a web-scraper. There are [many on the internet](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+scrape+a+website), but Stack Overflow is not a recommendation site, nor is it a build-your-software site. Please [edit] your question to be clear about what your request is.

Comment: @Alexander Nied Oh, you're right! Yeah so I guess good ol' copy paste will do the trick then